# Laravel 7 Unable to locate a class or view for component on production environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

After setting up a new droplet and deploying my laravel project i ran into a problem with my project.
When i try to access a page where i use laravel 7 components i get the following error:

```
Unable to locate a class or view for component [vbMenuItem].
```

After some debugging i cant figure out why this error occurs, on my local environment it works fine and on the old production environment that is running as a backup at the moment the same codebase works aswell.

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <x-vbMenuItem permission="view distributors" route="distributor" label="Distributors" asset="icons/Distributors.svg"/>
</ul>
```

And the component itsself:

```
class vbMenuItem extends Component
{
    public $permission;
    public $route;
    public $asset;
    public $label;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @param $permission
     * @param $route
     * @param $asset
     * @param $label
     */
    public function __construct($permission, $route, $asset, $label)
    {
        $this->permission = $permission;
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->asset = $asset;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.vb-menu-item');
    }
}
```

Has anyone run into this problem? If so i could use a little push into the right direction.

Comment: As you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-components), Blade component tags start with the string `x-` followed by the kebab case name of the component class, so in your case it would be `<x-vb-menu-item/>`, furthermore your class should be in pascal case so `VbMenuItem` and not `vbMenuItem`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will take a look at the coding standards for blade components. But does this actually impact the functionality of the application. If so, its strange that it does work locally and on a backup server but not on a newly created server.

Comment: There is a comment on this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32657#issuecomment-657147174), which might be cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error as you, and in my case it was because in linux it is case sensitive and I solved it by changing /app/View/Components/icons.php to Icons.php.

> Unable to locate a class or view for component [icons]. (View: /var/www/html/mekiot/resources/views/livewire/devices/team-group-views-list.blade.php)(View: /var/www/html/mekiot/resources/views/livewire/devices/team-group-views-list.blade.php)